# What's the point for the front to ensure a JWT token was issued by the back?

Tags: security, jwt, cryptography

Let's take the example of a web app using **JWT token authentication** with the RSA algorithm. Here are the steps of the authentication process :

- The front user authenticate by providing its credentials. They are sent through SSL to the API
- The back creates a payload carrying notably an expiration date and a user ID.  It uses its private key to sign the `header + payload` and send the resulting **JWT token** to the front
- <s>***(optional?)*** The front use the back public key to ensure the token was issued by it</s>
- The front includes the previous issued token in its request
- The back uses its public key to verify the token was issued by itself

Now, if an attacker crafts a malicious token and the front makes a request with it. The request won't succeed as the crafted token will not have been generated using the server private key (last step). The back will return `401 Unauthorized` status.

Invalid tokens are rejected. So, what is the point of ensuring the back was the legit issuer of the token?

It seems to me that such verification is a consequence of using JWT and not useful in my scenario.

What kind of attacks does ensuring the token issuer received by the front prevent?

It seems it would be only relevant in case the payload carries other data that influence the local app security behaviours (e.g. forbidding access to certain parts of an app locally for the end-user).

It guess that such verification is a consequence of using JWT and not useful in case I want to simply restrict the API use and the underlying data accessed through my routes.
I would like clarification on that matter or cyberattack scenarios where that security check could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

> Invalid tokens are rejected. So, what is the point of ensuring the
> back was the legit issuer of the token?

Since the backend will already deny the action if the token wasn't issued by the proper authority, it really doesn't serve any additional purpose here. One aspect could be that the parsing of the issuer is most likely cheaper than to perform a cryptographic action.

I think whether this opens an attack vector or not is really a question which cannot be answered in general since it's dependent on knowing how you use JWTs in your application. If you use the JWTs to store certain information which is then used by the frontend (e.g. permissions) it could enable the attacker to see certain menus, but as long as the sever denies the request to fetch all users for example, you're fine.

Generally speaking: Data from the frontend can and shouldn't be trusted from a security perspective since it can be modified in so many ways (localStorage / sessionStorage / databases / cookies / ...) - so by protecting the individual endpoints properly, you're already taking the proper countermeasures.